# Why do SparkFun make breakouts for circuit multiplexers?

Tags: multiplexer, breakout, sparkfun

I found [this product](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13906) on SparkFun. My first thought was "why do they need to make breakout boards for multiplexers, aren't there ready-to-roll muxes that do this kind of thing that already come in a DIP configuration"? And sure enough, [there are](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/multiplexer-switch-ics/7091980/) and naturally they're cheaper than buying whole PCB (obviously that link's not from SparkFun so it's gona be cheaper, but even with SparkFun's markup the solo IC is gonna be cheaper than a PCB).

So is the breakout board just to save people from having to worry about the pull-up resistor and decoupling capacitor that it includes?

Comment: I am not sure if this is an Engineering questions, but I would say they make them because (hopefully) someone buys them.

Comment: you could certainly use a "bare" dip. the breakout is suitable for a beginner because the pins are labeled and nicely lined up.

Comment: Yes looks pretty redundant when the same function is in a DIP. Of course there are many better muxes that are only available in SMT.

Comment: Because they can sell them and make money doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Because sometimes you want to prototype with the newest or devices with more features. Hobbyists often do not have access to in house fabs just for initial prototyping, while they will eventually get full pcbs made. And because some are more follow the Ikea instructions type of people instead of looking to replace similar but not exactly the same parts in someone else's project they are copying.

And obviously, they make them because there is a market for them. Economic tautology.